# GPG: Unsupported Binary Format

Tags: apt, kali-linux, gpg

Getting this error on running following command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Error:

```
GPG error: http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/grizzly Release: Detached signature file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_grizzly_Release.gpg' is in unsupported binary format
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to install to Kali some updates intended for a version of Ubuntu (12.04 LTS, *Precise Pangolin*) that reached End-of-Life at the end of April 2017. The particular Release file `apt-get` is accessing is from year 2014, and its GPG signature file from year 2016.

See for yourself:
http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/grizzly/

If your version of Kali is otherwise up to date, the contents of this repository should be way outdated for it. Why on earth would you expect that to work at all???

Nevertheless, it looks like the `Release.gpg` file of that repository on your local disk may have been corrupted on download. Have you tried running `sudo apt-get clean` and trying again?

If you want to get rid of that repository, check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and any `*.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. Find a line that looks like this:

```
deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/grizzly [...there may be something else here...]
```

and remove or comment it out. Then run `sudo apt-get clean`, and then try updating again.

Comment: ok whatever you said is right...i am new to linux...and don't know how i get here...just trying to get ride of it...but no success...sudo apt-get clean is not working either. Help

Comment: just removed entry....now its working

Comment: If the answer was good for you, please click on the hollow green check-mark near the vote count, to mark the answer as *accepted*.